# Probability distribution for number of quanta in lattice site

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

For some, it might look like a physics problem, but what I need is help with mathematical skills.

Suppose $n\times n$ lattice ( You can consider a matrix ), with entries $1$ in all the places (which represent one quanta particle per lattice site). Now suppose every unit of time, one Quanta from a random lattice point jump into some other random lattice point. This makes the number of quanta decrease by the amount of $1$ in the first site and increase by the amount of $1$ in the other site (where it goes after the jump).

After the time limit tends to infinite, I want to find the distribution for the number of quanta in a site. I want to show that it's turn out to be exponential so that the lowest energy site would be the highest. That is $e^{-\beta i}$ where $\beta $ is some constant and $i$ stands for number of quanta.

---

For those who do not understand the problem, the following [simulation](https://openprocessing.org/sketch/1065129) made by me can help.

Comment: Being a square lattice does not seem particularly important: it just means you have $n^2$ items and $n^2$ locations.  What is important is that you choose uniformly at random from non-empty locations and take an item, placing it in another location uniformly at random. An alternative could be to chose an item uniformly at random from all the items and move it, resulting in a different stable distribution (less close to geometric and instead closer to Poisson/binomial).

Comment: The ratio of the number of items to locations (let's call it $r$; you have used $r=1$) affects the stable distribution.  I suspect that if the number of locations is $n$ and the number of items is $nr$ then your formulation leads to a stable distribution which approaches geometric with parameter $\frac{1}{1+r}$ as $n$ increases, while the alternative leads to a stable distribution which approaches Poisson with parameter $r$ as $n$ increases. The expected number of items in each location remains $r$ in either case.